# FileNotFoundError: add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

Tags: ubuntu, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to install certbot on my Ubuntu 16.04 for letsencrypt certificates. 
Adding the repository goes wrong. Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

```
    wordpress@MV-WP02:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 335, in get_ppa_info
        ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 92, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
        return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
        return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
        lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
        capath=capath)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
        context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 122, in 
        shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 841, in shortcut_handler
        ret = factory(shortcut)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 407, in shortcut_handler
        return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 364, in __init__
        info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 347, in get_ppa_info
        _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 304, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
        lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
        return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
        lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
        capath=capath)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
        context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, a Google search got me to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897560/ssl-sslerror-x509-pem-lib-ssl-c3053), where the author said to do

```
# apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

and

```
# update-ca-certificates
```

which worked out the error for me. 
Looking at the packages that were affected, this may be a problem with SSL-Encryption, since this also fixed apt not wanting to update Docker repositories, which were also on an https address.